# What are good resources for a hard-working Calculus BC Student (offered only as a second year course in my highschool)?

Tags: calculus, online-resources, learning

I’m not sure if this is the best place to ask this…

I am currently a student in my school’s Calculus BC class, in which I would like to improve- not only in my actual grade, but actual abilities as an amateur mathematician.

I would say I am very hard working- I have tried many resources: multiple revisions of my class textbook (& built-in online resources), questions from other Calc BC teacher websites, JEE Calculus Differentials book, and I have begun looking into the MIT open source Calculus Textbook for single-variable Calculus. I also do go to my teacher for extra help to ask questions very often, try to time myself, etc.

This is my second year taking a calculus course- not to mention I am putting in a lot of effort, but not receiving the results I want to expect. If there is a better way to approach the course or studying for it, please share.

Thank you very much! TD;LR I’m having a hard time in my second-year calc course, are there any better resources I can use?

Comment: What are you having a hard time with, specifically?

Comment: I can’t really say. It’s not anything specific… I typically make many accuracy mistakes but also sometimes have a hard time grasping applications of what I’m learning especially when it involves geometric or trigonometric principles.

Comment: Self-scrutiny, when we remember to do it, generally helps with accuracy. Geometry is hard and my advice would be to not worry overtly about applications. There’s ancient debate about the need for applications in maths, but I’ll just say worries about them shouldn’t get in the way of your learning

Answer (score 0):

Khan academy's calculus content is really good and I found it incredibly helpful when I took calc 2.  In fact, I learned all the standard integration techniques almost entirely from their videos and practice problems.  They do a really good job of explaining things.  That's definitely the top resource I'd recommend.

Some other sites I've frequently found helpful in regards to learning calculus:

[Mathisfun: Calculus Index](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/)

[Betterexplained](https://betterexplained.com/articles/category/math/calculus/)

There's also the "Essence of Calculus" video series by 3Blue1Brown on YouTube, which does a great job of explaining several of the fundamental concepts in an intuitive and visual manner.